# How to check that certain strA is the substring of strB using Prolog?

Tags: prolog

So basically I use this code to check the substring:

```
substring(X,S) :- append(_,T,S), append(X,_,T), X \= [].
```

and my input is this:

```
substring("cmp", Ins)   % Ins is "cmp(eax, 4)"
```

But when I use swi-prolog to trace this code, I find this:

```
substring([99, 109, 112], cmp(eax, 4))
```

and obviously it failed...

So could anyone give me some help?

Comment: Your code works for me. Try just `substring("cmp", "cmp(eax, 4)").` The problem is where you instantiate Ins to be "cmp(eax, 4)".

Comment: Stop right there and change your data representation.  Representing assembly instructions as strings and analysing them using substring/2 is seriously ill-advised.

Answer (score 0):

SWI-Prolog has [recently changed](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=strings) the traditional string literals as 'list of codes' to a more memory efficient representation (starting from version 7).

As a consequence (among others more difficult to explain), append/3 doesn't work anymore for your task, unless you convert explicitly to list of codes.

Contextually, many builtins have been introduced, like [sub_string](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=sub_string/5)/5: for instance, try

```
?- sub_string("cmp(eax, 4)", Start,Len,Stop, "eax").
Start = Stop, Stop = 4,
Len = 3
```

Comment: From the the trace in the question - "cmp" become [99, 109, 112], so it's list of codes on the topic-starter's system.

Comment: I know, the question it's a bit blurry... Maybe before to answer I should inquiry version, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Make this string a term of the form `cmp(eax, 4)`. Here, in Prolog lingo, you have:

- the term `cmp(eax, 4)`
- with a functor `cmp/2`
- with a first argument the atom `eax`
- and a second argument the integer 4

Now that you have a term, you can use pattern matching in the head of your predicate (unification) to write predicates like:

```
apply_instruction(cmp(Reg, Operand) /*, other arguments as needed */) :-
    /* do the comparison of the contents of _Reg_ and the values in _Operand_ */
apply_instruction(add(Reg, Addend) /*, other arguments */) :-
    /* add _Addend_ to _Reg_ */
% and so on
```

How to make a term out of your input: there are many ways, the easiest would be to read one full line (depends on the Prolog implementation you are using, in SWI-Prolog, assuming you have your input stream in *In*):

```
read_line_to_codes(In, Line).
```

and then use a DCG to parse it. A DCG would look maybe something like:

```
instruction(cmp(Op1, Op2)) -->
    "cmp",
    ops(Op1, Op2).

instruction(add(Op1, Op2) -->
    "add",
    ops(Op1, Op2).

ops(Op1, Op2) -->
    space,
    op1(Op1), optional_space,
    ",", optional_space,
    op2(Op2),
    space_to_eol.

% and so on
```

You can then use `phrase/2` to apply the DCG to the line you have read:

```
phrase(instruction(Instr), Line).
```